# making a random move in tic tac toe -in C

Tags: c

I am doing a tic tac toe game in which the user competes against the computer. When the user chooses a spot, the computer should also make a move. However, I can't seem to get that to work. Whenever the user makes a move, it instantly asks me to make another one instead of filling one of the spots with the computer symbol (O)

I did the computer part in a different function from the user's (AI() and User()) and tried calling it inside each "else if" statement of the switch, however, that only keeps the game blinking and doesn't allow me to continue.

EDIT: I also tried to, instead of making it a function, do the whole AI() process inside "else if" statements, but it only seemed to work when the user chose 1, not for the rest of the options.

EDIT #2: I changed (k = 1) to (k == 1) in the code.

To make the following code easier to read I made it 1x3 instead of 3x3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct symbol{
    int marked;
    char symbol;
} SPOT;

SPOT spot1 = {0,'1'};
SPOT spot2 = {0,'2'};
SPOT spot3 = {0,'3'};

char symbol = 'X';
char compu = 'O';

void table();
int Check();
void User();
void AI();

int main(){
    system("cls");
    User();
    AI();
    Check();
    return 0;
}


void table(){
    printf("\n        %c   |   %c   |   %c ",spot1.symbol,spot2.symbol,spot3.symbol);
}


void User(){    
    char choice;

    do{
        loop++;
        do{
            table();
            printf("\n\nChoose a spot: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c",&choice);
        } while(choice < '1' || choice > '3');

        switch(choice){
            case '1': 
                if(choice == '1'){
                        system("cls");
                        if(spot1.marked == 1){
                            printf("\nThat spot is taken\n");
                        }
                        else if(spot1.marked == 0){
                            spot1.marked = 1;
                            spot1.symbol = symbol;
                        }
                }
                break;

            case '2': 
                if(choice == '2'){
                        system("cls");
                        if(spot2.marked == 1){
                            printf("\nThat spot is taken\n");
                        }
                        else if(spot2.marked == 0){
                            spot2.marked = 1;
                            spot2.symbol = symbol;
                        }   
                }   
                break;

            case '3': 
                if(choice == '3'){
                        system("cls");
                        if(spot3.marked == 1){
                            printf("\nThat spot is taken\n");
                        }
                        else if(spot3.marked == 0){
                            spot3.marked = 1;
                            spot3.symbol = symbol;
                        }   
                }   
                break;
        }while(Check() != 0 && Check() != 1);
    }

void AI(){
    int random,k;
    srand(time(NULL));
    do{
        random = rand() % 4;
        k = 0;
        if(spot1.symbol == symbol || spot2.symbol == symbol || spot3.symbol == symbol){
            k = 1;
        }
    }while(k == 1);

    switch(random){
        case '1': 
            if (random == 1){
                spot1.symbol = compu;
                spot1.marked = 1;
            }
            break;

        case '2': 
            if (random == 2){
                spot2.symbol = compu;
                spot2.marked = 1;
            }
            break;

        case '3': 
            if (random == 3){
                spot3.symbol = compu;
                spot3.marked = 1;
            }
            break;
    }
}

int Check() {
    if(spot1.marked == spot2.marked && spot2.marked == spot3.marked){
        if(spot1.symbol == symbol){
            return 1;
            printf("You won!");
        }
        else if(spot1.symbol == compu){
            return 0;
            printf("You lost!");
        }
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call User and AI alternately and only make one move at a time in each one.

Comment: would you tell me how that's done please? I've only been learning C for a few weeks

Comment: Move the `while(Check` loop to `main`

Comment: Is that an excerpt of your actual code or did you change anything? In the above code you have `while(k = 1);` which ireassigns k to 1 so the loop will be infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because each function in your `main` is called one after another.
Your program is stuck in the `User()` call

Try changing your `main` to :

```
int main(){
    system("cls");
    do{
        User();
        AI();
    }while(Check() != 0 && Check() != 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Removing the `do{...}while(Check() != 0 && Check() != 1);` in the `User` function

and change `while(k = 1);` to `while(k == 1);`

Comment: I did that but now whenever I choose a spot, the board goes blank and doesn't allow me to continue

Comment: Change `while(k = 1);` to `while(k == 1);` 
one `=` sets the value of `k`

Comment: It's now not working after I choose a second number, but I will continue from now on trying to see what I have wrong, thank you!